# Best way to save a grid and all children

Tags: c#, json, wpf

Solved but I'm going to remove the question rather than explain how I did it because my question was based on my logic of how I thought I'd solve it and I was barking up completely the wrong tree so the question and answer will be useless to anyone searching for an answer to this.

Comment: Can you post the code you've tried? It will be much easier for the community to help you if we have an idea of what the code looks like

Comment: The way you wrote the problem seems like you are hiding the real problem. You mentioned you need it to parse on a web server but parsing has nothing to do with web server. What do you actually need ?

Comment: I'm just being wary, it's a business application so I was trying to be sparing to not breach any data rules, basically this will be an application for clients to create an info board layout in wpf, which will then be saved and loaded by a web server which will then "host" the info board and provide the backend data for it. The web server part isnt really important, once I know how to save it I can go from there.

Comment: I've added some code to give a little context

Comment: You don't want to "save a grid". You want a data structure in memory, which is displayed and edited in a grid. Almost certainly, you want to write a class which represents a row, and then have an `ObservableCollection` of that class. You can then write code to convert that class to and from JSON, and to display and edit the collection in the grid. Think about that data structure first; that's the core of what you're doing. *Then* think about how you present it to the user. It's natural to think UI controls first, but you need to relearn that.